# neo4j - py2neo - Unable to place parameters into relationship on creation

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

If I run my python script over neo4j database, works ok:

```
from py2neo import Node, Relationship, Graph, cypher, authenticate

# set up authentication parameters
authenticate("localhost:7474", "user", "password")

# connect to authenticated graph database
sgraph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")

    a=raw_input("Input Name A: ")
    b=raw_input("Input Name B: ")
    graph = Graph()
    tx = graph.cypher.begin()
    tx.append("MATCH (c:Person {name:{a}}), (d:Person {name:{b}}) CREATE (c)-[:KNOWS}]->(d)", a=a, b=b)
    tx.commit()
```

but, when I tried to add parameters to relationship...:

```
a=raw_input("Input Name A: ")
b=raw_input("Input Name B: ")
z=raw_input("Input parameter of relationship z: ")
x=raw_input("Input parameter of relationship x: ")
graph = Graph()
tx = graph.cypher.begin()
tx.append("MATCH (c:Person {name:{a}}), (d:Person {name:{b}}) CREATE (c)-[:KNOWS{labelz:{z},labelx:{x}}]->(d)", a=a, b=b)
tx.commit()
```

I got this:

```
    tx.commit()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 333, in commit
    return self.post(self.__commit or self.__begin_commit)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 288, in post raise self.error_class.hydrate(error)

py2neo.cypher.error.statement.ParameterMissing: Expected a parameter named z
```

How do I have to place those variables to avoid that errors?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've provided the parameters for `a` and `b` at the end of your query, but you haven't provided `z` or `x`. Just add them on.

Comment: U'r absolutely right, testing some minutes ago I was able to do it. Sorry bother. But the other thing that I was trying to do is introduce as parameter the Label of the relationship, in this case "KNOWS", won't work even including at the end of the query.

Comment: In this case it might be a good idea to use string concatenation to dynamically add the relationship type into the query. Alternately, if you install APOC Procedures, you can use [apoc.create.relationship()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) to create the relationship instead of using CREATE. That will let you provide a string for the relationship type.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters can not be used as for property names, relationship types
 and labels :( 
[link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/d5f36a6f5f4c436d1117648c2fcf8e9a82714654),